# Blank area at the bottom of page as a result of relative positioning (CSS)

Tags: css

One of my divs' default position is about 800px down the page. I corrected that with:

```
position: relative;
top: -800px;
```

Now that I've moved everything up by 800px, there is a 800px gap at the bottom. I tried fiddling with the height, but 'auto' and '100%' does nothing, and '___px' messes up the layout.

How can I get rid of the gap?

Answer (score 1):

try using `max-height: 100vh` in your styles. `max-height` sometimes works better then `height` (it depents on what your trying to do). *vh* just a different % method.

Comment: That didnt work. I tried adding "max-height: 100vh" and removing the original "position: relative" code. 

Everything shifted back down and instead of a 800px gap at the bottom, I now have a 800px gap at the top.

Comment: hmm. could you use ```top: 0px; position: static;```?

Comment: Is there another object above it